# Nested dictonary in python

Tags: python

I am trying to update the values in the internal dictonary but it is updating in the both, I tried a lot but still facing the same problem. Thanks in advance.

```
arr = [1,2]
d_int = {'a':False, 'e':False, 'i':False, 'o':False, 'u':False}
d_main ={i : d_int for i in range(len(arr))}
print(d_main)
d_main[0]['a'] = True
d_main[1]['i'] = True
print(d_main)
```

Result:

```
{0: {'a': True, 'e': False, 'i': True, 
     'o': False, 'u': False}, 
 1: {'a': True, 'e': False, 'i': True, 
     'o': False, 'u': False}
}
```

Need something like this:

```
{0: {'a': True, 'e': False, 'i': False,
     'o': False, 'u': False},
 1: {'a': False, 'e': False, 'i': True,
     'o': False, 'u': False}
}
```

Comment: Change `d_int` to `d_int.copy()` and you'll have your output. You are referencing the same object.

Comment: Warning: If you have nested objects, like a dict in the dict, you need to copy them, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new without any programming experience in any programming language, For understanding why the problem happen, you'd better to know what is pointer in C programming language firstly.

---

`copy.deepcopy` is the best. `dict.copy` have same trouble in deep nested dict. as follows.

```
a = {"1": {"2": 2, "3": 3}, "4":4}

c = {1:a.copy()}
b = {1:a.copy()}

c[1]['1']['2'] = 5
c[1]['4'] = 40

print(c)
# {1: {'1': {'3': 3, '2': 5}, '4': 40}}
print(b)
# {1: {'1': {'3': 3, '2': 5}, '4': 4}}
```

But `copy.deepcopy` is work well with deep nested dict.

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = {"1": {"2": 2, "3": 3}, "4":4}

c = {1: deepcopy(a)}
b = {1: deepcopy(a)}

c[1]['1']['2'] = 5
c[1]['4'] = 40

print(c)
# {1: {'1': {'2': 5, '3': 3}, '4': 40}}

print(b)
# {1: {'1': {'2': 2, '3': 3}, '4': 4}}
```

Actually, this problem is not only happen to nested dict, other types as well, likes nested list, class with dict property and so on, and `copy.deepcopy` is work well.

Answer (score 1):

This is because all values of the `d_main` refer to the same dict object `d_int`. Changes to any one of them will reflect across all references. [Further read](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

To avoid the issue, ensure you create a new copy of the dict object during your list comprehension, using copying methods such as `.copy`.

```
arr = [1,2]
d_int = {'a':False, 'e':False, 'i':False, 'o':False, 'u':False}
d_main ={i : d_int.copy() for i in range(len(arr))} #modified.
print(d_main)
d_main[0]['a'] = True
d_main[1]['i'] = True
print(d_main)
#Output:
{0: {'a': True, 'e': False, 'i': False, 'o': False, 'u': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'e': False, 'i': True, 'o': False, 'u': False}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short workaround: Change d_int to d_int.copy() and you'll have your output. You are referencing the same object. Look at the difference in the id in these two cases:

### Case 1 (your attempt)

```
arr = [1,2]
d_int = {'a':False, 'e':False, 'i':False, 'o':False, 'u':False}
d_main ={i : d_int for i in range(len(arr))}
print(list(map(id,d_main.values())))
```

Returns:

```
[140545244867248, 140545244867248] # <-- they are the same
```

### Case 2 (possible work-around)

```
arr = [1,2]
d_int = {'a':False, 'e':False, 'i':False, 'o':False, 'u':False}
d_main ={i : d_int.copy() for i in range(len(arr))} # <-- .copy() added
print(list(map(id,d_main.values())))
```

Returns:

```
[140545244796464, 140545244798480]
```